# Display custom meta box to the admin sidebar not working

Tags: wordpress

I created a custom meta box to display some content inside the post display in the admin area and want it to show in the sidebar instead of below the wysiwyg editor. I added "side" to the context but nothing happens! I've been playing with this for many hours and haven't had any luck.

This is my code:

```
function add_custom_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box (
        'custom_meta_box',
        'Custom Meta Box Title',
        'show_custom_meta_box',
        'post',
        'side',
        'high'
    );
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_meta_box');

function show_custom_meta_box() {
    // here i have all the code
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm what version of WordPress you're using?

Comment: If I apply your exact code, it renders at the side, in top of `Publish` meta box. Try in a blank installation.

Comment: Hi @Jared Cobb thank you so much for your response, the version I am using is 3.5

Comment: Hi @brasofilo, how can I try it in blank installation?

Comment: Doesn't need to be a blank install (which you can have installing another WP in a folder in your server), just create a new user and log with it so you can check.

Comment: Hi @brasofilo thanks for your response, I created a new user as you suggested and when I logged in I was able to see the metabox in the sidebar! why is this? how can I make it show in the sidebar for me as the admin?

Comment: Have you seen my Answer just down here?

Comment: Hi @brasofilo, I kind of new to wordpress and really don't know how to implement that code with my meta box code. Should I replace what I did with yours?

Comment: I added your suggested code inside the functions page but still don't see any changes.

Answer (score 1):

Adapted from this [Q&A](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/64512/12615), the following will force the custom meta box into the second position in the side column.

Check the comments and note the caveat for `admin_init`.
It only works if the user hasn't rearranged the positions himself. When registering a new user, the position is set for him, as the hooks `admin_init` and `user_register` are attached to the same callback function.

```
// This fires at **every** page load, a better hook must be found
add_action( 'admin_init', 'set_user_metaboxes_so_14183498' ); 

// This fires when a new user is created
add_action( 'user_register', 'set_user_metaboxes_so_14183498' );  

function set_user_metaboxes_so_14183498( $user_id = null ) 
{
    // This is the metakey we will need to update  
    $meta_key = 'meta-box-order_post';

    // So this can be used without hooking into user_register
    if( !$user_id )
        $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 

    // Set the default order if it has not been set yet by the user. 
    // These are WP handles, PLUS our custom meta box handle
    if ( ! get_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, true ) ) 
    {
        $meta_value = array(
            'side' => 'submitdiv,custom_meta_box,formatdiv,postimagediv',
            'normal' => 'postcustom,commentsdiv,slugdiv,revisionsdiv',
            'advanced' => '',
        );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to reset the admin configuration? An updated metabox works for new users, but me as the admin, I still see the metabox in the old position.

Comment: I think the easiest would be looking in the database. I don't think removing one meta  value would cause troubles, but as usual backup just in case before mangling with the db